# MySQLdump leads to exceeding max connections. Skip-Quick as a solution?

Tags: mysql

Every night I do a full mysqldump of a 17G DB in MySQL 5.7.32. This worke for years, now I am doing some heavy load on inserts during the night which caused at exactly the backup time the connections to rise to max_connections which led to connections errors.

As the Server has enough RAM 64G (30G free), I increased max_connections from 150 to 300 in a first reaction.

However looking at the dump command I found the option -- [quick (also enabled by default)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html) which tells me that it is exporting row by row.

```
--single-transaction --routines --quick --compact
```

I am thinking of changing this to `--skip-quick.` but dare to change this since I would need to check the restore again and this is very time consuming. Would you advise changing to skip-quick?

Comment: Consider moving to dba.stackexchange.com -- MySQL (and mysqldump) get more traction there.

Comment: `--quick` sets _several_ options; you should change only those you explicitly want to change.